# Yii2 Database setup and code generation after basic install

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying out Yii and installed the beta of version 2 of the basic application. However, I can't find any documentation on how to proceed after the installation. I like to know how/where I should design the database tables and how to trigger the code generation. I'm planning to use a MySQL database.

I now have a basic web application running (in /web) that I can login to (the user accounts are hardcoded configured User class). There is a lot of documentation on version 1 of the framework, but I would expect some pointers on how to get started with version 2.

Comment: Look at gii: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/568/create-crud-with-yii2/

Comment: Thanks, this actually told the basics I needed: that I could design the tables in MySQL and that there is a specific url to access the code generation (http://localhost//web/index.php?r=gii)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table you should design in mysql tool or use [migrations](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/console-migrate.md) to create table. The use [gii](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/gii.md) to generate models. In Yii2 you can access gii with `http://localhost/web/index.php?r=gii` url

Comment: To help other starters: one you have created the tables you can access gii at: http://localhost//web/index.php?r=gii

Answer (score 0):

Get installed [Yii giix extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/giix).

In your config file

```
       'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'pick up a password here',
        ),
       ),
```

Then, visit the URL **localhost/testdrive/index.php?r=gii** We will be prompted for a password, which should be the one that we just entered in the above application configuration.

If you stuck anywhere go through [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Here is the [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app) , Explained whole process including Giix(code generator) , Hope this would help

Comment: Can you at least summarize the process in your answer here?

Comment: Although giix does look very nice, I am playing around in yii version 2 and I cannot find info on how to install giix for that.